# Find the corners of a square given a collection of points, 3 corners are always given in these points

Tags: python, opencv

I'm currently coding a project in python and am running into a pit of an issue, my code takes in a bunch of coordinates that come off of a scanned object. The array always has the coordinates of three corners and then a bunch of others coordinates anywhere else on the board, split into a 4x4 layout except for the fourth corner. I was originally using openCV's minAreaRect() to find the perimeter, but I realized that this wont work if the coordinates are in a triangle shape. I could use some help figuring out the four corners of the rectangle, it can also have any possible rotation.

The first image is drawn from real data that I was building this off of and the second image is data I made up to test the software, I am also coding in python.

Image 1 (real data)
coords =  [[[1712, 2090], [1570, 1948], [1248, 2090], [1260, 1940], [1714, 1948], [1224, 2420]]]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Raymr.png)
Image 2 (fake data)
coords = [[[1000,1000],[2000,2000],[1000,2000]]]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPGVO.png)

Comment: See cv2.minAreaRect()

Comment: Three points can form multiple different rectangles. This is not uniquely solvable without an assumption of the angle. Your first image can get a close solution, but the second images has many solutions.

Comment: As a new member you may want to read [ask] and especially how to share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).